# XMLHttpRequest to Post HTML Form

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, forms, http-post

**Current Setup**

I have an HTML form like so.

```
<form id="demo-form" action="post-handler.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="name" value="previousValue"/>
   <button type="submit" name="action" value="dosomething">Update</button>
</form>
```

I may have many of these forms on a page.

**My Question**

How do I submit this form asynchronously and not get redirected or refresh the page? I know how to use `XMLHttpRequest`. The issue I have is retrieving the data from the HTML in javascript to then put into a post request string. Here is the method I'm currently using for my zXMLHttpRequest`'s.

```
function getHttpRequest() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    
    return xmlhttp;
}

function demoRequest() {
       var request = getHttpRequest();
       request.onreadystatechange=function() {
             if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                   console.log("Response Received");
             }
       }
       request.open("POST","post-handler.php",true);
       request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       request.send("action=dosomething");
}
```

So for example, say the javascript method `demoRequest()` was called when the form's submit button was clicked, how do I access the form's values from this method to then add it to the `XMLHttpRequest`?

**EDIT**

Trying to implement a solution from an answer below I have modified my form like so.

```
<form id="demo-form">
       <input type="text" name="name" value="previousValue"/>
       <button type="submit" name="action" value="dosomething" onClick="demoRequest()">Update</button>
</form>
```

However, on clicking the button, it's still trying to redirect me (to where I'm unsure) and my method isn't called?

**Button Event Listener**

```
document.getElementById('updateBtn').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
                                evt.preventDefault();
                                
                                // Do something
                                updateProperties();
                                
                                return false;
                            });
```

Comment: You tagged jQuery but there is no jQuery code... Do you want to use jQuery or pure javascript ?

Comment: Sorry misclick. Just javascript

Comment: I posted an answer that you can use via jquery though

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending POST data with a XMLHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: To prevent the default form action, set an event listener on the _form's submit event_, instead of the button's click event. (And still call `evt.preventDefault();`)

Comment: In your edit captioned "Button Event Listener", where exactly would you put that code? into the functions demoRequest() body? why the return false statement?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The POST string format is the following:

```
name=value&name2=value2&name3=value3
```

So you have to grab all names, their values and put them into that format.
You can either iterate all input elements or get specific ones by calling `document.getElementById()`.

*Warning:* You have to use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for all names and especially for the values so that possible `&` contained in the strings do not break the format.

Example:

```
var input = document.getElementById("my-input-id");
var inputData = encodeURIComponent(input.value);

request.send("action=dosomething&" + input.name + "=" + inputData);
```

---

Another far simpler option would be to use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) objects. Such an object can hold name and value pairs.

Luckily, we can construct a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object from an existing form and we can send it it directly to [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)'s method *send()*:

```
var formData = new FormData( document.getElementById("my-form-id") );
xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: Do I override the button's `onClick` function and point it to my `XMLHttpRequest` method?

Comment: @DiscoS2 Yes. Do you have any other event handlers registered for the click event?

Comment: Not for this form no.

Comment: Thank you for expanding on your answer more. I am having issues submitting the form. I have remove the action and method from the `<form>` tag as it was still posting via `HTML`. How do I call my `javascript` method?

Comment: @DiscoS2 How did you assign the event listener? Can you show us the code (in your answer - not in a comment, please)?

Comment: Added the code in my original question. However, its not a listener... unsure of how to do this?

Comment: @DiscoS2 Try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsHgu/ (add an ID to your button and register an event listener as provided in the fiddle).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36728/discussion-between-disco-s2-and-comfreek)

Comment: Your code does not work with file uploads... I used `var formData = new FormData( document.getElementById("my-form-id") );` and `formData` is empty.

Comment: @Black According to [MDN on FormData objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), it should work. Did you use a POST or GET request?

Comment: @ComFreek, It works now. It was not working because of a wrong header (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020648/upload-file-to-server-asynchronously-via-form-and-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: This doesn't work in an addon.  how to do this without overriding the onsubmit()?  addons/extensions do not allow overriding onsubmit due to security reasons.

Answer (score 19):

The [ComFreek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18592868/938111) is correct but a complete example is missing.

Therefore I have wrote an extremely simplified working snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge, chrome=1"/>

<script>
"use strict";
function submitForm(oFormElement)
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function(){ alert(xhr.responseText); }
  xhr.open(oFormElement.method, oFormElement.getAttribute("action"));
  xhr.send(new FormData(oFormElement));
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST"
      action="post-handler.php"
      onsubmit="return submitForm(this);" >
   <input type="text"   value="previousValue" name="name"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This snippet is basic and cannot use `GET`. I have been inspired from the excellent [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_FormData_objects). Have a deeper read of this MDN documentation to do more. See also this [answer using `formAction`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843756/938111).

Comment: When I use this method my form is submitting multiple(2) times. Any suggestion?

Comment: Today I just found a small fix for this. I have changed `onsubmit="submitForm(this);"` to `onsubmit="return submitForm(this);"`. Rest of your code remains same. This solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @MayurPatel very much for your feedback. I have just edited the snippet to reflect your contribution. Have fun ;-)

Comment: You should use `oFormElement.getAttribute("action")` in case you ever add an input field named "action", which will override your `oFormElement.action`. Same goes for method ofc

Comment: Thank you @h3n for your advice  I have just applied your trick. Should I do the same for `oFormElement.getAttribute("method")`? I am a bit afraid my original tiny snippet is becoming more complex... What do you think? Have fun 

Comment: @olibre Async is by default true, so you don't need it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open#Parameters

Answer (score 4):

By the way I have used the following code to submit form in ajax request.

```
 $('form[id=demo-form]').submit(function (event) {

    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    // let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");


    // serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();


    // fire off the request to specific url

    var request = $.ajax({
        url : "URL TO POST FORM",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });
    // callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){


    });

    // callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

    });

    // callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // reenable the inputs

    });

    // prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: The OP does **not** want to use jQuery.

Comment: @ComFreek He didn't mention in question. Now he mentioned in comment. I posted answer before this comment.

Comment: Thanks for posting Awais, I found this thread and I DO want to use jQuery

Comment: If we wanted ajax we would have used jq so no thanks

Answer (score 0):

With pure Javascript, you just want something like:

```
var val = document.getElementById("inputFieldID").value;
```

You want to compose a *data* object that has key-value pairs, kind of like

```
name=John&lastName=Smith&age=3
```

Then send it with **request.send("name=John&lastName=Smith&age=3");**

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem too, I think.

I have a input element with a button.  The `onclick` method of the button uses `XMLHttpRequest` to POST a request to the server, all coded in the JavaScript.

When I wrapped the input and the button in a form the form's action property was used.  The button was *not* `type=submit` which form my reading of HTML standard (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attributes-for-form-submission) it should be.

But I solved it by overriding the `form.onsubmit` method like so:

```
form.onsubmit = function(E){return false;}
```

I was using FireFox developer edition and chromium 38.0.2125.111 Ubuntu 14.04 (290379) (64-bit).

Answer (score -1):

```
function postt(){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var y = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var postdata= "username=y&password=z"; //Probably need the escape method for values here, like you did

    http.open("POST", "chat.php", true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postdata.length);

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(postdata);
}
```

---

how can I post the values of y and z here from the form

Comment: If you have a separate question, you should create one rather than posting an answer on an already existing question.  Thank you.