# Upload file to server asynchronously via form and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php

I need to upload a file by only using vanilla.js, no frameworks are allowed.

**Form:**

```
<form id="fileUploadForm" action="fileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</form>
```

I placed the button outside of the form, because it is at another position in the HTML.

```
<button id="btnUpload">Upload</button>
```

This is the upload Script. I am using `FormData` to get the form data, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18592868/4684797).

```
<script>

document.getElementById("btnUpload").addEventListener("click", function() {
    fileUpload("fileUploadForm");
});

function fileUpload(pFormId) 
{
    debugger;
    var form = document.getElementById(pFormId);
    var formData = new FormData( form );  //returns no data!

    var request = getHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
              console.log("Response Received");
              document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = request.responseText;

        }
    };
    request.open("POST", "fileUpload.php", true);
//    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
    formData.append("action","test");  //Add additional POST param
    request.send(formData);
}

function getHttpRequest() 
{
    let xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}
</script>
```

I am using the PHP upload script from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

```
<?php

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
     echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

I attached the debugger to my javascript and found out that `formData` is empty and does not contain the file.
[image]

This is what I get from PHP:

[image]
Sorry, file already exists.

[image]
Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.

Even though the file does **NOT** already exists AND the file format is jpg.

---

Update:

This is what I get in the developers console network tab:

```
Request Payload:
------WebKitFormBoundaryKjnjAyPoCQ7MU1x6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileToUpload"; filename="Koala.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryKjnjAyPoCQ7MU1x6--
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Check what your browser sends. F12 > network > click the request and check what the parameter names are.

Comment: Good hint! I update my question.

Comment: You should not set `Content-type` header when uploading via `FormData`

Comment: @MartinAdámek, Ahh ok, now I get `Sorry, your file is too large.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.` after commenting `request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");` out! Thanks! The file is only 750KB big though :/?

Comment: And what is the size of that file? You probably reached the limit of `500000` bytes

Comment: It is not very big to be honest, `Content-Length: 775897` (775KB). Is there a way to allow larger file uploads?

Comment: 775897 > 500000 indeed. That is your script that sets the `500000`, so just increase that number.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the `content-type` header, that will be set automatically by browser when using `FormData`. That way content-type will also contain form boundary used to separate form data (the thing like `------WebKitFormBoundaryKjnjAyPoCQ7MU1x6--` that separated the payload data).

Answer (score 0):

I'd modify the code slightly.

```
document.getElementById("btnUpload").addEventListener("click", function() {
    fileUpload("fileUploadForm");
});
```

You're binding the event on `click`. I'd modify this and attach a `submit` event to the form.

The closure will get the event target as callback:

```
document.getElementById("fileUploadForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) { // <- pay attention to parameter

    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action so we stay on the same page.
    fileUpload(e); // pass the event to your function
});
```

Now, on to your `fileUpload` function.

```
function fileUpload(e) 
{
    debugger;
    var formData = new FormData( e.target );  // pass the event target to FormData which serializes the data    

    var request = getHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
              console.log("Response Received");
              document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    };

    request.open("POST", "fileUpload.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
    request.send(formData);
}
```

Disclaimer: **I did not test this at all**, so don't copy paste and expect it to work!

Comment: This will not work unless you remove the `content-type` header. The problem is not in passing form reference to `FormData` constructor, that part is fine (see MDN, they use the same code in examples).

Comment: @MartinAdámek fair enough! Thanks for the correction.